# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [msf_updates/pose_sensor]: can't locate node [pose_sensor] in package [msf_updates]

Tags: ros

I am following this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_sensor_fusion/Tutorials/Introductory%20Tutorial%20for%20Multi-Sensor%20Fusion%20Framework
 and have compiled the package in the catkin workspace. I tried to get the new namespace and launch the filter but I am unable to do so because I get an error that the pose_sensor node cannot be located. I have `source`'d my `devel/setup.bash`. 
However, that hasn't fixed the problem. I still get the error:

```
NODES
  /msf_viconpos_sensor (msf_updates/pose_sensor)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [msf_updates/pose_sensor]: can't locate node [pose_sensor] in package [msf_updates]
```

EDIT:

After adding the missing code, here is the new error I get when I run `catkin_make`:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cannot open /home/yukti/catkin_ws/src/fix-unused-typedef-warning.patch: No such file
glog_catkin-master/CMakeFiles/glog_src.dir/build.make:101: recipe for target 'glog_catkin-master/glog_src-prefix/src/glog_src-stamp/glog_src-patch' failed
make[2]: *** [glog_catkin-master/glog_src-prefix/src/glog_src-stamp/glog_src-patch] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:502: recipe for target 'glog_catkin-master/CMakeFiles/glog_src.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [glog_catkin-master/CMakeFiles/glog_src.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  3%] Linking CXX shared library /home/yukti/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmsf_timing.so
[  3%] Built target msf_timing
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

EDIT 2:

After running a different make command as follows:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
```

I was able to successfully compile. However, I still get the same error that;

```
can't locate node [pose_sensor] in package [msf_updates]
```

EDIT 3: Edit 2 was incorrect because I had an incorrect src folder in my home folder which contained a CMakeLists.txt. If following the correct order, I still get a compilation error akin to Edit 1.

EDIT 4: cmake failed after adding all the changes from the pull request. Here is the log:

```
Base path: /home/yukti/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/yukti/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/yukti/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/yukti/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/yukti/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/yukti/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/yukti/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/yukti/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/yukti/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/yukti/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/yukti/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/yukti/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.12") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/yukti/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 12 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - asctec_mav_framework (metapackage)
-- ~~  - catkin_simple
-- ~~  - ethzasl_msf
-- ~~  - glog_catkin
-- ~~  - msf_timing
-- ~~  - sensor_fusion_comm
-- ~~  - asctec_hl_comm
-- ~~  - asctec_hl_gps
-- ~~  - asctec_hl_interface
-- ~~  - msf_core
-- ~~  - msf_distort
-- ~~  - msf_updates
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'asctec_mav_framework'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(asctec_mav_framework-master/asctec_mav_framework)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'catkin_simple'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(catkin_simple-master)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ethzasl_msf'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ethzasl_msf/ethzasl_msf)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'glog_catkin'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(glog_catkin-master)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'msf_timing'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ethzasl_msf/msf_timing)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:169 (add_executable):
  add_executable cannot create target "msf_timing_tests" because another
  target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is an
  executable created in source directory
  "/home/yukti/catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_msf/msf_timing".  See documentation for
  policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:79 (_catkin_add_executable_with_google_test)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:28 (_catkin_add_google_test)
  ethzasl_msf/msf_timing/CMakeLists.txt:46 (catkin_add_gtest)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sensor_fusion_comm'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ethzasl_msf/sensor_fusion_comm)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- sensor_fusion_comm: 5 messages, 2 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'asctec_hl_comm'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(asctec_mav_framework-master/asctec_hl_comm)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Generating .msg files for action asctec_hl_comm/Waypoint /home/yukti/catkin_ws/src/asctec_mav_framework-master/asctec_hl_comm/action/Waypoint.action
Generating for action Waypoint
-- asctec_hl_comm: 18 messages, 3 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'asctec_hl_gps'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(asctec_mav_framework-master/asctec_hl_gps)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'eigen3'
--   Found eigen3, version 3.2.92
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindEigen.cmake:62 (message):
  The FindEigen.cmake Module in the cmake_modules package is deprecated.

  Please use the FindEigen3.cmake Module provided with Eigen.  Change
  instances of find_package(Eigen) to find_package(Eigen3).  Check the
  FindEigen3.cmake Module for the resulting CMake variable names.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  asctec_mav_framework-master/asctec_hl_gps/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Found Eigen: /usr/include/eigen3  
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'eigen' but neither 'eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'eigen_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  asctec_mav_framework-master/asctec_hl_gps/CMakeLists.txt:21 (catkin_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'asctec_hl_interface'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(asctec_mav_framework-master/asctec_hl_interface)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   signals
--   system
--   thread
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'msf_core'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ethzasl_msf/msf_core)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindEigen.cmake:62 (message):
  The FindEigen.cmake Module in the cmake_modules package is deprecated.

  Please use the FindEigen3.cmake Module provided with Eigen.  Change
  instances of find_package(Eigen) to find_package(Eigen3).  Check the
  FindEigen3.cmake Module for the resulting CMake variable names.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ethzasl_msf/msf_core/CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)


-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'eigen' but neither 'eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'eigen_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  ethzasl_msf/msf_core/CMakeLists.txt:44 (catkin_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:169 (add_executable):
  add_executable cannot create target "test_similaritytransform" because
  another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is
  an executable created in source directory
  "/home/yukti/catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_msf/msf_core".  See documentation for
  policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:79 (_catkin_add_executable_with_google_test)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:28 (_catkin_add_google_test)
  ethzasl_msf/msf_core/CMakeLists.txt:78 (catkin_add_gtest)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:169 (add_executable):
  add_executable cannot create target "test_static_statelist" because another
  target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is an
  executable created in source directory
  "/home/yukti/catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_msf/msf_core".  See documentation for
  policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:79 (_catkin_add_executable_with_google_test)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:28 (_catkin_add_google_test)
  ethzasl_msf/msf_core/CMakeLists.txt:80 (catkin_add_gtest)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'msf_distort'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ethzasl_msf/msf_distort)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'msf_updates'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ethzasl_msf/msf_updates)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/yukti/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/yukti/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the right CMake files unfortunately and the admins of the repo do not seem very interested in maintaining it.

However, this pull request contains the necessary CMakeLists to launch `pose_sensor`

https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_msf/pull/141/files

Specifically, here is the diff that you need

https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_msf/pull/141/files#diff-a855f8508d144ac9c52a05344bfeba5cR7

```
install(TARGETS
    pose_sensor
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
)
```

in this file https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_msf/blob/20a4a61e1a8a1051bc752203e3b4f17795c0264d/msf_updates/src/pose_msf/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Thank you for this. But I changed the file, redid catkin_make and source'd it and I still got the same error. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Can you check if the binary is present in your catkin workspace

Comment: So basically, my devel folder does not have a /bin and /etc folder. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: @cjds I explained my process by editing the question. I was not able to successfully compile after making the changes you suggested.

Comment: Could you get all the code in that Pull Request and post what happens https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_msf/pull/141/files

Comment: @cjds cmake failed after the new changes.